# Matlab error in function calling

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-compiler

I have written a function in matlab but it is showing error. Please help me out.

this is my main calling file.

```
for j= 1:10
   for i= 1:81
     MAG1(i,j)=20*log10(MAG(i,j));
     satplotm(j,MAG1(i,j),PHA(i,j)); %error
     hold on
  end
```

and this is my function

```
function satplotm(j,m(k,j),theta1);
```

the lines which i have written in bold letters are showing error and this is the error,

> Error: File: satplotm.m Line: 1 Column: 22 Unbalanced or unexpected
>   parenthesis or bracket.
>
> Error in Templates (line 471)
>        satplotm(j,MAG1(i,j),PHA(i,j));

please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you read your error message (protip: read error messages), you have an extra/missing parenthesis or brakect on line 1.

That is because defining a function input as an index of a matrix make no sense.

Define your fucntion as `function satplotm(j,m,theta1);`

and then set `m` to be a single thing, as you already do in the for loop.